# ReactDnD - how do I access the object returned from beginDrag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

e.g. I have

```
const source = {
    beginDrag() {
        return { foo: `bar` }
    },
}
```

how do I access this inside a component wrapped with connectDropTarget? The props I get e.g. inside

```
const target = {
    drop(props) {

    },
}
```

are only the props that I passed down to this component like usual.

Comment: figured this one but it won't let me answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯